# Put a <a> hyperlink in a django message

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using django messages and i want to put an hyperlink in it.

view.py:

```
from django.contrib import messages

def my_view(request):
    messages.info(request,"My message with an <a href='/url'>hyperlink</a>")
```

Obviously, in my page, i see the html code and no hyperlink. How to treat the message as an htlml code ?

Hope this is clear.

Comment: While the answers here can work, I strongly suggest the answer provided to a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10124845/26196 -- it offers more potential flexibility without some of the caveats of other methods.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Strings in Django templates are automatically escaped. You don't want your raw HTML to be auto-escaped, so you should either pass the string to the [`safe`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter:

```
{{ message|safe }}
```

or disable autoescape with the [`autoescape`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape) tag:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ message }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 69):

If you don't want to turn off autoescaping on all messages/templates, you can use mark_safe for that particular message:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

messages.info(request, mark_safe("My message with an <a href='/url'>hyperlink</a>"))
```

And if you maybe have some unsafe parts of your message, you can use cgi.escape to escape those parts.

```
from cgi import escape
messages.info(request, mark_safe("%s <a href='/url'>hyperlink</a>" % escape(unsafe_value)))
```

Comment: You have to be using SessionStorage for the messages framework in order for this to work - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053258/how-do-i-output-html-in-a-message-in-the-new-django-messages-framework

Comment: I guess this should not be enabled for every message, as they could contain user provided data, just to be on the safe side. Thank you for your answer

Comment: A got: "<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: 'cgi' is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.13".  Anyone knows any equivalent to use instead of cgi?

Answer (score 14):

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html, another option would be to use `format_html` which will apply escaping to (unsafe) arguments, similar to the escaping in the Template system.

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

messages.info(request, format_html("My {} <a href='/url'>{}</a>", some_text, other_text))
```