# Print html tags in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is it possible in django to print a string keeping the html tags?

So if I write {{ variable }} the html content inside the variable doesn't get interpreted by the browser as html.

(Really a newbie)

Thanks

Comment: Will this page help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053258/how-do-i-output-html-in-a-message-in-the-new-django-messages-framework

Answer (score 2):

You can use the escape filter `{{variable|escape}}`

Same as php's `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars`

Answer (score 1):

That happens by default, because of Django's autoescaping. You have to specifically mark content as safe before it will be interpreted as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the safe filter `{{variable|safe}}`

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like less of a Python/Django question and more of an HTML question.

My first guess would be something like a  tag, but here's an SO question discussing the best way(s) to display HTML on an HTML page (without rendering it): [Display HTML code in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html)