# Error in the following django code?

Tags: python, django

I am using django messaging framework to display a one time message. Everything is working fine except its not being rendered properly. Not able to figure out the issue.
Python code:

```
@receiver(user_signed_up)
def on_user_signed_up(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    context={'request':request}
    msg='You have completed the first step of <a href="%s">Getting started with MDN</a>' % wiki_url(context, 'MDN/Getting_started')
    messages.success(request, msg)
```

jinja2 code:

```
<div class="one time message">
        {% if messages %}
        <ul>
            <li>{{ _('messages') }}</li>
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

Desired output: You have completed the first step of [Getting started with MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Getting_started)

```
   My output: You have completed the first step of <a href"replaced url">Getting started with MDN</a>
```

Note: wiki_url is a utility that converts the path into url.

Comment: How is it not being rendered properly?

Answer (score 0):

Adding extra_tags='safe' marks the message as safe in django messages framework. The answer that starts with "another option is to..." is the one worked for me 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10124845/4297741

Comment: By adding tag you did not mark message as safe, extra `if` in template required... You can do it with just 1 `mark_safe` call...